# I have to get a number with 10000 digits; what is the best java data type?

Tags: java

For a [competitive problem](http://www.spoj.com/problems/PALIN/) I need to get 10000 digit number as input.

I used `Biginteger`  which takes lots of time and I am getting TLE error , which is the data type suitable for this?

Comment: Hi Krishna, I tried to make your title a title.

Comment: Obviously, the full error would be helpful.

Comment: Do you really need a number? Keeping a `String` would be fine here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem does not require handling the input as an integer at all -- for all that the problem requires, that integers is **just a string of digits**, ie. a string.